# Merging two datasets based on column in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I have two datasets originally from the same source, but due to categorization I found it necessary to divide these. 
I was wondering how to merge these datasets back based on missing values from two columns? 
In other words, I need all the rows (columns are identical as they are from the same source) from dataset 1 and then based on a columns indicating years and country code when rows are missing from dataset 1 extract the rows from dataset 2?

```
df1 <- read.table(
text =
"Year, Data,Country
1,2,US
3,2,US
5,1,US
1,3,UK
2,5,UK
4,3,UK
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
df1

df2 <- read.table(
text =
"Year, Data,Country
1,3,US
4,5,US
5,8,US
2,9,UK
3,4,UK
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
df2

df3 <- read.table(
text =
"Year, Data,Country
1,2,US
3,2,US
4,5,US
5,1,US
1,3,UK
2,5,UK
3,4,UK
4,3,UK
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
df3
```

The df3 extracts the missing year values from df1 and df2. How would this extraction be coded?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Jens. Please read [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Comment: Also, don't use the ````rstudio```` tag unless your question is directly related to the Rstudio IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a `full_join` and select the non-NA value between `Data.x` and `Data.y` using `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2,  by = c('Country', 'Year')) %>%
   mutate(Date = coalesce(Data.x, Data.y)) %>%
   select(-Data.x, -Data.y) %>%
   arrange(Country)

#  Year Country Date
#1    1      UK    3
#2    2      UK    5
#3    4      UK    3
#4    3      UK    4
#5    1      US    2
#6    3      US    2
#7    5      US    1
#8    4      US    5
```

The same logic in base R :

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = c('Country', 'Year'), all = TRUE), 
          Data = ifelse(is.na(Data.x), Data.y, Data.x))[names(df1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!!! Next time please provide a sample of your data and not a link or an image or a link to an image. For example, I create sample data to test solution using `read.table()`. Data can be small since if a solution works on four or five rows, it will work on all rows. This is especially true if the solution is vectorised, as the one below is.

```r
df1 <- read.table(
text =
"Year, Data
1,2
2,4
3,2
5,1
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(
text =
"Year, Data
1,3
2,4
4,5
5,8
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

Next we simply extract the row that isn't in the first data frame and `rbind` to the first data frame. We need to specify `drop = T` so that the rows are binded by row number, which places the row from `df2` in the fourth row of the new data frame, otherwise it will be placed at the end of the new dataframe.

```r
new_yr <- which(!(df2$Year %in% df1$Year))

df <- rbind(df1[, , drop = T], df2[new_yr, , drop = T])

df
Year Data
1    1    2
2    2    4
3    3    2
4    5    1
5    4    5
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply. Clearly, I missed several guidelines in regards to posting. I will make changes based on your example to further extend my question precisely tomorrow as I cannot edit my question today.
The datasets in question are also categorized by country codes and therefore I am unable to specify the drop = T as the row numbers varies with year and countries.

Comment: Have you tried the code I've posted? drop = T should still work in your case.

Comment: Yes, the application of the code provides the original dataset with one more observation. 
Admittedly, my original post was a poor description of the problem, so the miscommunication is on my end.